# All React Native Firebase modules must be of the same version - can't use Auth

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-firebase

I installed RNF from starter kit provided by Invertase. I am using RNF app, database, analytics, auth. Everything worked fine until I needed the auth module. It throws an error on app startup (on Android, haven't tried iOS):

```
    ...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:86 
You've attempted to require '@react-native-firebase/auth' version '6.0.3', however, 
the '@react-native-firebase/app' module is of a different version (6.0.0).

    All React Native Firebase modules must be of the same version. 
Please ensure they match up in your package.json file and re-run yarn/npm install.
```

But I checked in package.json of all the modules are of version 6.0.3, and my package.json also looks good:

```
{
  "name": "meditationapp",
  "version": "6.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "run:android": "react-native run-android",
    "run:ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 11 Pro Max\"",
    "build:apk": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "test": "jest",
    "prepare": "patch-package",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "6.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "6.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "6.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "6.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.3.3",
    ...
```

Import in App.tsx:

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database'
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'
```

Things I've tried:

1. Delete node_modules and run `npm install`
2. Installed v6.0.0 instead of 6.0.3
3. Deleted android/app/build

Can't think of anything else to try, but the error does not go away. 
It's working fine with analytics and database, only auth is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to be an issue with the caches.

1. I deleted the npm cache and metro bundler cache (manually, on Windows the are located at C:\Users<user>\Appdata\Roaming)
2. deleted the node_modules folder in the project
3. Ran `npm install`

The project now has all RNF modules with version 6.0.3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You should note that all packages of `@react-native-firebase/...` are equal to `@react-native-firebase/app`.

To solve this problem you need to `update the relevant packages` and then `reset the npm cache`:

1. `npm update @react-native-firebase/app`
2. `npm update @react-native-firebase/analytics`
3. `npm update @react-native-firebase/..` //all of the firebase packages    (updated)

And finally reset the npm cache

4. `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: I also had to delete the metro bundler cache, otherwise it was still complaining...

Answer (score 2):

I created a project with:

```
npx @react-native-community/cli init --template=@react-native-firebase/template <name>
```

and I got this issue. But then I created a basic project like `react-native init <name>` and I installed

```
@react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/auth
```

or any product, and the issue improved.

Comment: I spent like two hours removing and installing node_modules and pods, but just `npm i --save <library_in_question>` worked like a charm. I dont know what to say...

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to remove ~ or ^ icon from version on package.json and all versions must be the same:

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "18.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "18.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "18.8.0"
```